# Change in select query

Tags: php, mysql

I have Adjacency list mode structure like that

[image]

by this query

```
SELECT t1.name AS lev1, t2.name as lev2, t3.name as lev3, t4.name as lev4
FROM category AS t1
LEFT JOIN category AS t2 ON t2.parent = t1.category_id
LEFT JOIN category AS t3 ON t3.parent = t2.category_id
LEFT JOIN category AS t4 ON t4.parent = t3.category_id
WHERE t1.name = 'ELECTRONICS';
```

getting result like that

[image]

but i want to get result like that, there is any option do it

[image]

thanks in advance

Comment: The `UNION`-keyword might be the right direction: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/union.html

Comment: i want to count all category under ELECTRONICS category

Comment: @vikastyagi So out of the above results, all you really want is `19`?

Comment: @DaveRandom i want to get result 9, if i use that query-> SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT t1.name ) AS lev1, COUNT( DISTINCT t2.name ) AS lev2, COUNT( DISTINCT t3.name ) AS lev3, COUNT( DISTINCT t4.name ) AS lev4
FROM category AS t1
LEFT JOIN category AS t2 ON t2.parent = t1.category_id
LEFT JOIN category AS t3 ON t3.parent = t2.category_id
LEFT JOIN category AS t4 ON t4.parent = t3.category_id
WHERE t1.name = 'ELECTRONICS'; after that i have problem sum row value

Comment: The problem you are going to hit is the recursion levels which MySQL doesn't do well.  Unless some other avenue I'm not experienced with, you don't know how many levels deep it may go... OR... are you specifically only looking for a maximum of 3 levels deep (from the top) in your category listings?

Comment: @DRapp, plz could u tell me more explain if i have lot of level, how can i this thing more gud way

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it's difficult to count the amount of sub-categories of a category with your current setup. Not only is the depth of your menu limited by the amount of `LEFT JOIN`'s you add, it's also impossible to tell which categories are directly linked to a category more then one level deep.

A excellent solution to this problem is using a `nested set` structure for your menu, [you can read more here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model). More explanation how to do this with mysql [here](http://www.fliquidstudios.com/2008/12/23/nested-set-in-mysql/).

Answer (score 1):

You'll need a UNION, and I suggest removing the duplicates of entries at their respective levels.  Also, no need to include "NULL" values if your intention is to present to users as in web apps...

```
select L1.Category_ID,
       L1.name, 
       "1" as HierarchyLevel, 
       count( L2.Category_ID ) as NextLevelCount
   from Category L1
        LEFT JOIN Category L2
           on L1.Category_ID = L2.Parent
   where L1.name = "ELECTRONICS"
   group by L1.Category_ID
UNION
select L2.Category_ID,
       L2.name, 
       "2" as HierarchyLevel,
       count( L3.Category_ID ) as NextLevelCount
   from Category L1
        JOIN Category L2
           on L1.Category_ID = L2.Parent
           LEFT JOIN Category L3
              on L2.Category_ID = L3.Parent
   where L1.name = "ELECTRONICS"
   group by L2.Category_ID
UNION
select L3.Category_ID,
       L3.name, 
       "3" as HierarchyLevel,
       count( L4.Category_ID ) as NextLevelCount
   from Category L1
        JOIN Category L2
           on L1.Category_ID = L2.Parent
           JOIN Category L3
              on L2.Category_ID = L3.Parent
              LEFT JOIN Category L4
                 on L3.Category_ID = L4.Parent
   where L1.name = "ELECTRONICS"
   group by L3.Category_ID
UNION
select L4.Category_ID,
       L4.name, 
       "4" as HierarchyLevel,
       1 as NextLevelCount
   from Category L1
        JOIN Category L2
           on L1.Category_ID = L2.Parent
           JOIN Category L3
              on L2.Category_ID = L3.Parent
              JOIN Category L4
                 on L3.Category_ID = L4.Parent
   where L1.name = "ELECTRONICS"
```

This is obviously fixed to 4 levels but will union them into a single list, but no duplicates as you presented.  I also tacked on the hierarchy level just for reference purposes.  In order to get the counts at each level, you must do a LEFT JOIN to the next level, otherwise, you'll miss possible items at the level you are trying to retrieve, but the others SHOULD remain as INNER JOINs.

If you are dealing with products, I would think that if not after 4 levels deep they can't find something, there's a bigger problem :)

Comment: thanks for relay, you gave me right answer what i asked, but still i have problem if have level more than 4

Comment: @vikastyagi, really... more than 4 levels?  Doing more than that, I would actually write a stored procedure to query the data out.  Not having MySQL where I'm at, can't do that on the fly.  Can you show a hierarchy that gets deeper than 4 levels?

Answer (score 1):

As a point of interest, because it might be too much work and different from what you have to be an "answer", I would suggest you look into the concept of "Modified Pre Ordered Tree Traversal". There's a great [explanation by Gijs Van Tulder](http://www.sitepoint.com/hierarchical-data-database-2/).

It will require additional fields on the table to store the hierarchy data, and extra code to maintain that structure, but it can make tree-structures *much* easier to deal with in a relational database engine.

Basically, as well as the usual `parent_id` that we store with trees, we also store a `left` and a `right` value. When correctly populated, it's then easy to get "all children of node" by simply selecting all nodes where `node.left > parent.left` and `node.right < parent.right`, regardless of the depth of the nodes.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
SELECT name FROM category WHERE name = 'ELECTRONICS'

UNION

SELECT t2.name FROM t2 INNER JOIN category as t1 ON t2.parent = t1.category_id WHERE t1.name = 'ELECTRONICS'

UNION

SELECT t3.name FROM t3 INNER JOIN category as t1 ON t3.parent = t1.category_id WHERE t1.name = 'ELECTRONICS'

UNION

SELECT t4.name FROM t4 INNER JOIN category as t1 ON t4.parent = t1.category_id WHERE t1.name = 'ELECTRONICS'
```

Comment: You are somewhat on right track, but due-to the nested level hierarchy, you would be missing many elements as things like "Plasma", "LCD", and "Tube" are all under "TELEVISION" which is under "ELECTRONICS"